# Fabric build failing - error 137 from run script at eval $DIR$PATH_SEP$VALIDATE_COMMAND statement

Tags: ios, crashlytics, xcodebuild, google-fabric

My local builds are working fine, but when I committed the code to our Continuous Integration system (Bamboo) it fails with:

> build 20-Jul-2018 15:53:44        /bin/sh -c
>   /opt/build/bamboo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPod-MPOS-harfjwxrkcthyddsjdtfqhtdwyui/Build/Intermediates/iPod-MPOS.build/StarmountRelease-iphoneos/redacted.build/Script-EAF8153E20FD4CD600392FC3.sh
>   build 20-Jul-2018 15:53:44     build  20-Jul-2018
>   15:53:44  /opt/build/bamboo/agent01/xml-data/build-dir/redacted/engage/client/ipod/Libraries/Fabric/Fabric.framework/run:
>   line 18: 90824 Killed: 9
>   "/opt/build/bamboo/agent01/xml-data/build-dir/redacted/engage/client/ipod/Libraries/Fabric/Fabric.framework/uploadDSYM"
>   5a908e0f7d21d8b959e4a35b453a40c9664252c4
>   716b300bdbdc9f0233758958b31552b0cb2b2470deb64ee6a02f062dbe9b2924
>   validate run-script build 20-Jul-2018 15:53:44    Command /bin/sh failed
>   with exit code 137

The Fabric installation is manual (not CocoaPods).

Answer (score 0):

Same problem (with installation step from the doc)
**Downloading dependencies**
*Installing Crashlytics 3.10.2 (was 3.10.5 and source changed to `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` from `https://github.com/cocoapods/specs.git`)
Installing Fabric 1.7.7 (was 1.7.9 and source changed to `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` from `https://github.com/cocoapods/specs.git`)*

**just downgrade version**
pod 'Fabric', '1.7.7'
pod 'Crashlytics', '3.10.2'

Comment: downgrading Fabric is not an option for me.  First and foremost - can someone provide a definition for what "error 137" actually means?  My theory is access to the Crashlytics cloud is block from our Continuous Integration build servers - but that's just a theory.